# Im still able to select any file after declaring to only accept image files in an input

Tags: html, angular, forms

Here is my form:

```
<form #optionsForm="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="saveOptions()" id="optionsForm">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="customFile">Icon</label>
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" 
               name="customerFile" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" required>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile" 
               id="customerFileLabel">Select Icon</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="logo.imageInBase64" class="row">
      <label id="previewLabel">Preview:</label>
      <div class="report-logo">
        <img alt="{{logo.name}}" src="{{logo.imageInBase64}}" class="logo-image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" aria-hidden="true" 
            [disabled]="!optionsForm.valid">
      <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Save
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thats how it looks without and with a file selected:

[image: Withot Icon selected]

[image: With icon selected]

I have two problems currently. Firstly i tried to define with `accept="image/*` that only images should be accepted by the input. But the only thing it does is opening the file manager with a image filter, but im still able to switch to all files and select a non image file. Is there a way to avoid that?

[image]

The second problem is the formvalidation. I disable the button if the form is invalid with `[disabled]="!optionsForm.valid"`.I put the required attribte to the input, so that should invalidate the form and disable the button if no input is selected, but it currently is not doing that. The form is still valid even if i did not select any file.

Comment: you can't control switching to "All files" by the user in uploader dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify extension with the image as shown below. This will allow only a specified extension for file selection and upload. I hope this works for you.

```html
<form #optionsForm="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="saveOptions()" id="optionsForm">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="customFile">Icon</label>
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" 
               name="customerFile" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" required>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile" 
               id="customerFileLabel">Select Icon</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="logo.imageInBase64" class="row">
      <label id="previewLabel">Preview:</label>
      <div class="report-logo">
        <img alt="{{logo.name}}" src="{{logo.imageInBase64}}" class="logo-image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" aria-hidden="true" 
            [disabled]="!optionsForm.valid">
      <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Save
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```